# Mark all from java packages as @Depracated in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, deprecated

Is it a way to automatically mark the whole content of java package (subpackages, classes, methods, members) as `@Depracated` using eclipse (preferably) or any other tool if there is too many files to make it manually.

Comment: All classes in all subpackages would be enough, though, right? That implicitly makes all their methods and members deprecated, too.

Comment: Yes classes seems to be enough. But how to make it automatically?

Comment: Don't know. That's why you got your +1 from me ;-)

Comment: Does sound like something the Refactoring tools should able to do, though.

Comment: @Thilo I checked it's enough. See also [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/deprecation/deprecation.html#when]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `sed` to mark all classes in the current directory and below (tested in Cygwin). Navigate to the desired folder and run:

```
for file in $(find . -name *.java); do sed -i 's/\(public class\)/@Deprecated\n\1/g' $file; done
```

To also mark interfaces just add it like this:

```
for file in $(find . -name *.java); do sed -i 's/\(\(public class\|interface\)\)/@Deprecated\n\1/g' $file; done
```

**EDIT**

As @ŁukaszRzeszotarski points out, you can do this in Eclipse with the Search/Replace tool. Just mark the resources where you want to perform the operations, then press `Ctrl + h`. Fill it out like this:

[image: Search]
Then, press `Replace`, and fill it out like this:

[image: Replace]
All done!

Comment: I was going to object that this only works for public classes, but I guess you don't need it for package-private ones anyway (since no one outside the package see them). You need to add interfaces, though.

Comment: This is a useful answer, but doesn't meet the criteria of the question (performing the refactor with Eclipse). Might be worth mentioning that in the answer for clarity.

Comment: @seanhodges: OP asked for a solution with "Eclipse or other tool", so I think this meets his requirements.

Comment: @Keppil ah yes, I see it now in the body text.

Comment: Looks good, but that's a pity that for example eclipse doesn't have such functionality in 'Refactor' section. sed is ok, but requires installation of http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm when you are using windows.

Comment: @ŁukaszRzeszotarski: I use it as part of `Cygwin`, but yes, you do need an external installation. It is quite addictive, after a while you wonder have you ever managed without `sed` and the other included tools. :)

Comment: @Keppil Yes I used Cygwin. From the other hand going into that direction we can write regular expression and run it in Eclipse's find and replace tool :)

Comment: @ŁukaszRzeszotarski: True. :)

Comment: @Keppil Still I would prefer some plugin. Maybe we should write one ;). What if words 'public class' or 'interface' exist in javadoc section, etc. Of course can be handled by regex but...

Comment: If you want to catch all, including indenteds, static inner classes, abstract and final and enums, then `^(\s*(public|protected|private)?\s+(static\s+)?(abstract\s+)?(final\s+)?(class|interface|enum)\s+)` works as the search string

Answer (score 3):

Try creating a file called `package-info.java` and deprecate the package.

```
@Deprecated
package foo;
```

Deprecating `foo` and will not deprecate `foo.bar`.

*Tested on Java 7; Eclipse.*

Comment: Ah, I wasn't sure whether this was supported. A pity.